# SQL Query to get the emp and corresponding manager from Emp Audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have employee audit table which has the multiple row of each employee. EX:Emp_Table

```
Emp_id Manager_id Date
1         1       Sep'13
1         2       Sep'13  
1         3       Oct'13
2         1       Jan'13
2         1       Feb'13
3         1       Jan'13
3         1       Mar'13
3         2       Feb'13
3         2       Jan'13
```

Output I'm looking for the table is

> Latest employee changes Rows

According to the table above following output is required

```
  Emp_id  Manager_id   Date
    1         3       Oct'13  
    2         1       Feb'13
    3         1       Mar'13
```

I tried the below query

```
select emp_id,Manager_id,MAX(Date)
from Emp_Table
Group by emplid
```

Comment: isn't it `manager_id` 3 for `emp_id` 1?

Comment: @今草顿웃.. Updated the Question. Thanks for point the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which is an analytic function that generates sequential number. In this case, the sequential number is generated for every `emp_id` sorted by `date` in descending order. The latest change will have the value of `1` in `rn` which you can filter out.

```
SELECT Emp_ID, manager_ID, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT  Emp_ID, manager_ID, Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
) a
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp_id,
       Manager_id,
       Date
FROM Emp_Table
WHERE (emp_id, Date) in 
                       (select emp_id, 
                               MAX(Date)
                          from Emp_Table
                      group by emp_id)
```